# Load Home after Login Call was successful

Tags: react-native, navigation

I implemented the login page and the login service for my react native app. Now I want to load the home screen, when the login was successful. I am able to do it with this.props.navigation.navigate/.push("home"), but I always can go back from there to the login page. How can I load the screen as a starting point?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you are navigating seems fine, but if I were you I would create separate stack navigators for Login pages as well as the home page.

If you're using react-navigation, there is a simpler way to do it introduced in the new APIs.

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

export default createAppContainer(
createSwitchNavigator(
{
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  App: "Your homepage screen",
  Auth: "Your login screen",
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
}
)
);
```

and in AuthLoadingScreen check for a token which determines if the user is logged in like this

```
class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
this._bootstrapAsync();
}

// Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

// This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
// screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
};

// Render any loading content that you like here
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ActivityIndicator />
    <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Divye, thanks a lot. Cant I do the check directly in the Navigator class? Thanks, Jan

Comment: The user already has a splash screen.  I think this is a code for the convenience of developers. Users load bars don't like to watch.

Comment: Surely yes but inherently the Authloadingscreen is where the token will be checked for at first. It's just that I prefer to segregate components
@iosbegindevel using switchNavigator would help him as it resets the stack with the initial screen as the home screen once authenticated which would, in turn, get the back behavior requested.

Answer (score 1):

On the page that specifies the Welcome screen, use local storage values to retrieve the data you have saved and compare the values to set the Welcome screen.

### **Example**

```js
const screenData = AsyncStorage.getItem("startScreen");
const stackScreen = createStackNavigator(
  {
    home: {
      screen: homeScreen
    },
    login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
  }
  {
   initialRouteName: screenData === "loginsucess" ? "home" : "login"
   }
```

Comment: Hi, is this function to go back to the first page? I want to achieve that the there is no way to go back to the login page after the login call was successful. The home should be the starting point. I am thinking about adding logic to the app.js to check if the user is already logged in and then move him to the login page or to the home screen

Comment: @Sylber   I've edited my answers to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, works as I wanted. Now I will change it a little bit for the future

Comment: React Navigation updated the library with the intent to create specific Switch Navigators as requested with improved performance. 
Also retrieving data from AsyncStorage is an async process which might cause delays hence it is advised to have a loader screen where you perform such logic.